# How does the C compiler (clang) enforce const?

Tags: c, constants

With Clang, the following :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   double const x = 1.234;
    double *p = (double *) &x;
    /* Same with double *p = &x; but with a mere warning from clang
       Clang++ does raise an error in this case.
    */
    *p = 5.678;

    printf("*p = %f\n", *p);
    printf(" x = %f\n", x);

    if (&x == p) {
        printf("&x = %p\n", &x);
        printf(" p = %p\n", p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

gives the output:

> *p = 5.678000
>   x = 1.234000 
>  &x = 00000080288FFEA8 
>  p = 00000080288FFEA8

How exactly does the compiler do this? How can the compiler successfully compile *and* avoid, say, the following output:

> *p = 5.678000 
>  x = 5.678000 
> &x = 00000080288FFEA8 
>  p = 00000080288FFEA8

Comment: Casting away `const`-qualification and then modifying the value results in undefined behavior.

Comment: basically the compiler can do whatever it wants, since you said you wouldn't mutate that data, it can put it in the text section and copy it in everywhere, it can just use the actual literal representation of that directly in the asm... it can do whatever it wants...

Comment: Might be interesting to post the disassembler

Comment: @ChristianGibbons well formally you're right, but I didn't expect this from "undefined behavior"; like I tacitly assumed there are *some* limits of its zaniness. Simply claiming a value is at a certain memory location while it isn't in reality, is pretty extreme.

Comment: @Amaterasu Unexpected things can happen primarily because compilers will aggressively optimize in ways that can be rather surprising.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The behaviour on modifying an object which was originally `const` via a cast which removes that `const` is undefined.

Whether or not a compiler warns you about undefined behavior is up to the compiler. To do so in full generality is impossible.

Optimising compilers will make assumptions based on the fact that your program does not contain undefined behaviour. The Clang output is consistent with it substituting `1.234` for `x` in that `printf` call; that's legitimate since `x` is not allowed to change.

Comment: tio.run gives `1.234` for `x` with Clang but not with gcc or tcc

Comment: Could be that the compiler simply didn't perform a load operation to check the new value of x since it shouldn't change.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: My money is on it hardcoding the `printf` in the first case, and essentially ignoring the `const` in the second.

Comment: I was curious, so I compiled and dumped the binary, and it does, indeed, look like it is just pushing in a hard-coded value to `printf`.  I even added an `x + *p` print and that, too, used a hard-coded value.  (I did modify the code to use `int`s so it was easier to read the dump).

Comment: The problem is, that for implicit casts, clang will still compile this code. I was reading Stroustrup's "Tour on C++" where he claims "The compiler enforces the promise made by const". Indeed, it seems a C++ compiler does this, but a C compiler not necessarily. So what's `const` good for besides optimization in C?

Comment: @Amaterasu: `const` is quite a new addition to C, and in my humble opinion was a pretty poor idea.

Comment: @Amaterasu It is true that C and C++ do not treat the `const` keyword the same.  Optimization is a good enough reason for the keyboard alone, but it also can help prevent you from overwriting a value that should not change, but if you go out of your way to do it anyways... well C isn't a language that holds your hand.  If you point the gun at your foot, turn off the safety, and pull the trigger, don't be surprised when a bullet goes through your foot.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: Although C++ gives you the ability to blow your whole leg off.

Comment: Quite true.  I'm happy to take my chances with the foot-shooting.  C is a small enough language that you can get a pretty good idea of what leads to shooting yourself in the foot and learn to avoid such practices as second nature.

Answer (score 5):

Bathsheba hypothesized that the compiler could be passing in hard-coded values to printf.  I figured I'd look at the generated assembly and see if we could verify the hypothesis.

I made a few slight modifications to the code in question: Changed the `double`s to `int`s to make it easier to understand what I'm seeing in the assembly, and I also added another print statement adding the values together.

Compiled with `clang -std=c11 -g -O2`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{   int const x = 1;
    int *p = (int *) &x;
    *p = 2;

    printf("*p = %d\n", *p);
    printf(" x = %d\n", x);
    printf(" x + p = %d\n", x + *p);

    if (&x == p) {
        printf("&x = %p\n", (void *)&x);
        printf(" p = %p\n", (void *)p);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

disassembled code (just main section):

```
0000000000400510 <main>:
  400510:   53                      push   %rbx
  400511:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  400515:   c7 44 24 0c 02 00 00    movl   $0x2,0xc(%rsp)
  40051c:   00 
  40051d:   bf 10 06 40 00          mov    $0x400610,%edi
  400522:   be 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%esi <----- hard-coded 2 passed in
  400527:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400529:   e8 c2 fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <printf@plt>
  40052e:   bf 19 06 40 00          mov    $0x400619,%edi
  400533:   be 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%esi <----- hard-coded 1 passed in
  400538:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40053a:   e8 b1 fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <printf@plt>
  40053f:   bf 22 06 40 00          mov    $0x400622,%edi
  400544:   be 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%esi <----- hard-coded 3 passed in (2+1)
  400549:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40054b:   e8 a0 fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <printf@plt>
  400550:   48 8d 5c 24 0c          lea    0xc(%rsp),%rbx
  400555:   bf 2f 06 40 00          mov    $0x40062f,%edi
  40055a:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40055c:   48 89 de                mov    %rbx,%rsi
  40055f:   e8 8c fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <printf@plt>
  400564:   bf 38 06 40 00          mov    $0x400638,%edi
  400569:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  40056b:   48 89 de                mov    %rbx,%rsi
  40056e:   e8 7d fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <printf@plt>
  400573:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400575:   48 83 c4 10             add    $0x10,%rsp
  400579:   5b                      pop    %rbx
  40057a:   c3                      retq   
  40057b:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

The compiler is, indeed, passing in hard-coded values.

Comment: That's a nice analysis. Have an upvote! (For those readers who don't follow assembler, `xor    %eax,%eax` is the idiomatic way of setting a register to 0 - it's faster than moving 0 to the register.)